# Is there a samsung tv 2015 non-tizen emulator?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

How can I test a samsung tv app on 2015 non-tizen models without a device? I've looked for an emulator, but the only ones I've found were for 2014 models http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/SdkReleaseNote and tizen models http://www.samsungdforum.com/Tizendevtools/Sdkdownload. But I need to see how my app would run on 2015 non-tizen samsung tv and there seem to be no software to emulate the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2015 non-tizen model is compatible with 2014. There are only very minor spec changes in 2015 non-tizen.

So you can use SDK for 2014 model basically.

There is no plan for make SDK for 2015 non-tizen.